# How to conditionally mutate according to group and sum?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science

I'm trying to select a group for a word according to the sum of its TF-IDF.

This my Data `sof`

```
sof <- data.frame('Text'=c("I have an apple apple and a banana","I have an apple apple and a banana",
                       "I have an apple apple and a banana", "You drive a car with gloves",
                       "You drive a car with gloves", "I like your cat dog horse and shoes",
                       "I like your cat dog horse and shoes","I like your cat dog horse and shoes",
                       "I like your cat dog horse and shoes", "I have all PC xBox PS Switch games",
                       "I have all PC xBox PS Switch games","I have all PC xBox PS Switch games",
                       "I have all PC xBox PS Switch games","I have all PC xBox PS Switch games",
                       "I have all PC xBox PS Switch games"),
                  'Word'=c("apple","apple","banana","car","gloves","cat","dog","horse","shoes","PC",
                         "xBox","PS","Switch","games","all"), 
                  'tfidf'=c(0.127,0.127,0.309,0.203,0.203,0.169,0.341,0.0533,0.331,
                            0.275,0.143,0.231,0.275,0.143,0.231),
                  'Thema' = c("AN","AN","V","AU","AU","AR","G","ALG","ALG","WOH",
                              "AN","AU","WOH","AN","AU"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

What I'm trying to do is:

- Group by `Text`
- sum the `tfidf` according to thier `Thema`
- Add a new Variable `sWords` That hosts all the found words from `Word` in `Text`
- Add a new Variable `sThema` which hosts `Thema` of the highst sum in step 2

I tried:

```
sSof <- sof %>% group_by(Text) %>% 
    summarize(SumTFIDF = sum(unique(tfidf), na.rm = TRUE),
              sWords = paste(toString(unique(Word)), collapse = "; "),
              sThema = paste(toString(unique(Thema)), collapse = "; "))
```

But I get all the possibale entries of `Thema` and I need only the one, the sum of which's `Word`is the highst.

The Result:

```
> sSof
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Text                                SumTFIDF sWords                           sThema     
  <chr>                                  <dbl> <chr>                            <chr>      
1 I have all PC xBox PS Switch games     0.649 PC, xBox, PS, Switch, games, all WOH, AN, AU
2 I have an apple apple and a banana     0.436 apple, banana                    AN, V      
3 I like your cat dog horse and shoes    0.894 cat, dog, horse, shoes           AR, G, ALG 
4 You drive a car with gloves            0.203 car, gloves                      AU
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Text                                SumTFIDF sWords                           sThema     
  <chr>                                  <dbl> <chr>                            <chr>      
1 I have all PC xBox PS Switch games     0.649 PC, xBox, PS, Switch, games, all WOH
2 I have an apple apple and a banana     0.436 apple, banana                    AN      
3 I like your cat dog horse and shoes    0.894 cat, dog, horse, shoes           G 
4 You drive a car with gloves            0.203 car, gloves                      AU
```

Only one `Thema`has to stay, and that's the one with the words with the hightst Sum of `tfidf`

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you show your expected output ?

Comment: Sure, I edited the expected results in the question

Comment: Why did you delete the last copy of this question? I'll repeat the comment I made and the comment I was typing as you deleted...

Comment: When you say *"sum the tfidf according to thier Thema"*, that means you need to group by thema. So Group by both Text and Thema for the summing. Otherwise you can't know which thema has the highest sum.

Comment: I'm also confused by your `sum(unique(tfidf))`. In your raw data, I see that rows 1 and 2 are identical, and you don't want to double count them. But rows 4 and 5 have the same Text, TFIDF, and Thema, *but different words*. Do you really want to count them as the same? It seems like a better approach might be to de-duplicate the data frame to remove identical rows like 1 and 2, but keep the different rows like 4 and 5...

Comment: @Gregor Sorry if I caused any confusion, but I reliezed I had a very bad data representation and I did it all with this new sample data set

Comment: This data presentation is much nicer, but next time please just edit your question. I had started writing an answer, and I deleted it when your question disappeared.

Comment: ```sum(unique(tfidf))``` Because I don't want to add the same score of a word more then once

Comment: oh man! I'm terribly sorry, and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but you could divide it into multiple steps and `join` them.

```
sof %>%
  group_by(Text, Thema) %>%
  summarise(sum_tfidf = sum(unique(tfidf))) %>%
  right_join(sof) %>%
  left_join(
    sof %>%
      group_by(Text) %>%
      summarise(sWords = str_c(Word, collapse = ", "))
  ) %>%
  slice(which.max(sum_tfidf))


# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   Text [4]
  Text                                Thema sum_tfidf Word    tfidf sWords                          
  <chr>                               <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>                           
1 I have all PC xBox PS Switch games  WOH       0.275 PC     0.275  PC, xBox, PS, Switch, games, all
2 I have an apple apple and a banana  V         0.309 banana 0.309  apple, apple, banana            
3 I like your cat dog horse and shoes ALG       0.384 horse  0.0533 cat, dog, horse, shoes          
4 You drive a car with gloves         AU        0.203 car    0.203  car, gloves
```